# Algorithm for farthest coprime

Tags: algorithm, primes

Given an array of n numbers, replace each element with it’s farthest coprime in the range [2, 250]. Example, the farthest coprime for 2 is 249 and for 243 is 2.

Could anyone help me with algorithm with the best complexity yo solve this?

Comment: Seems like for numbers 2 to 125, 249 will be the farthest comprime. For anything beyond that, 2 will be the farthest coprime.

Comment: I partly agree with 249. It's prime, so it can't have a common divisor with anything below it. But 2 and e.g. 240 aren't coprime, so for numbers beyond 125, it's not that easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the number range is small I would go for some application of sieve.

```c
for (int i = 2; i <= N; ++i)
{
    if (N % i == 0)
    {
        sieve[i] = 1;
        for (int j = 2; j * i <= 250; ++j)
        {
            sieve[i * j] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

After that using this, you will look for smallest value `sm` for which `sieve[sm]` is 0 and also largest value `lg` for which `sieve[lg]` is 0.
Then among them get from which the distance to `N` is maximum. That is your answer.

Sieve has the complexity of `O(nloglogn)`. And the looping to find the farthest will be `O(n)`. So overall complexity is `O(nloglogn)`.

#### Logic behind this:

Simply we are marking the values that are not co-prime for this particular number N.

Then we just loop over to get the smallest and largest number which are coprime to the given number. We then calculate the distance and then make the largest one as the answer.

Comment: @Appstarted.: Check my answer.

Comment: Why check sieve for values of 1? Wouldn't this get you the distance to the farthest not co-primes?

Comment: @user43389.: I will get back to you regarding this...I am busy a bit this weekend.

Comment: @user43389.: Thanks for showing the typo...Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For the farthest coprime of N from the range [2, 250], the candidates are:

- 250 is a candidate if N is not divisible by 2 or by 5.
- 249 is a candidate. It's prime, so it's surely co-prime with all numbers below 249.
- Final candidate is the first prime number that N is not divisible by (e.g. for N=240, that prime is 7). A list of prime numbers from 2 up to 250 need not be computed at run time, but can be spelled out as array initialization.

Of these (up to) three candidates, choose the one farthest from N.